# AND and OR in one IF Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to know why this one fired "treehit"

Why does `&&347<=100` not work?

script-snippet:

```
if(Tree[i]["x_coord"]<=(Lumber[0]["x_coord"]+100)||Tree[i]["x_coord"]<=(Lumber[0]["x_coord"]-100)&&Tree[i]["y_coord"]<=(Lumber[0]["y_coord"]+100)){
    console.log("treehit");
    $("#Tree_"+i).css("background","yellow");
}
```

log:

```
id: 11 XY Test: 10<=100||10<=-100&&347<=100
calc.js:36 treehit
```

Comment: "*Why does &&347<=100 not work?*" 347 is not less or equal to 100.

Comment: What log do you refer to?

Comment: Because `10<=100` already evaluates to `true`, the rest of the `||` expression is discarded.

Comment: Andy Ray had the right clue for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic you want is:

```
(10 <= 100 || 10 <= -100) && 347 <= 100
```

Put parenthesis around your logic to make your grouping explicit.

What you're executing right now with Javascript precedence is:

```
10 <= 100 || (10 <= -100 && 347 <= 100)
```

Comment: If I or others answer your questions, make sure to click the empty check mark next to the answer to mark it as correct, to help others find it, and give me fake internet points

Comment: yeah was short on time back then and stackoverflow puts a correct answer on a 10min hold
you was just too fast